# Visual Studio 16.3.4 + Python Tools 16.3 Interactive Window breaks debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio

Python Tools Interactive Window became pretty much useless since the last update to Visual Studio. 
Normally I would be able to test my buggy code in the interactive window, but now, suddenly, entering an incorrect command triggers a proper Visual Studio error and breaks the process.

As seen in the image - before, I would see the error in the interactive window and the Visual Studio would not pop up and break debugging.

[image: As seen in the image - before, I would see the NameError in the interactive window and the Visual Studio would not pop up and break debugging.]

Any suggestions if this is a problem on my side?

Comment: Switch to visual studio code ;-)

Comment: @NickMartin That's not helping...

Comment: In all seriousness, it is a possible solution. We've migrated all our python development to VS Code now and honestly, I find it a much better developer experience than VS. It would also help if you provided some more information. What version of VS are you using? What Python version?

Comment: Well, you motivated me to have another look at VSCode and maybe give it a second chance. Previously I found it difficult to use and missing many features of the proper Visual Studio. However it seems I must either switch to it or wait for another VS update...

Comment: VS 16.3.4 and Python Tools 16.3 and Python itself 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by the kind folks at https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/5827.

The solution is to use a legacy debugger, option found in Options>Python>Debugging.